# Django audit log - 'action_date' field is naive, how do I prevent warnings

Tags: django

I'm using django-audit-log to track changes to my data. It works great other than one fairly small thing: whenever a new entry is being added to the log table a warning is generated:

```
DateTimeField received a naive datetime while time zone support is active.
```

I traced this back and discovered it was the action_date field in the log table which is causing it.  Does anyone know how I can make this value timezone-aware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe pytz can come in handy here. It can convert naive datetimes into timezone aware ones. Have a look here: http://pytz.sourceforge.net/.

If you happen to have a naive date like this string "`2012-02-21 10:28:45`", you may proceed like this:

```
from django.utils.dateparse import parse_datetime
naive = parse_datetime("2012-02-21 10:28:45")
import pytz
pytz.timezone("Europe/Helsinki").localize(naive, is_dst=None)
datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 21, 10, 28, 45, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Helsinki' EET+2:00:00 STD>
```

(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#usage).

Comment: Thanks Jingo. The other consideration was where to do this. I've had to update the models/managers.py inside audit-log as seen on http://pastebin.com/FWCkcTqM and unfortunately it doesn't appear that the package is being maintained any longer